# Get items that have less available quantity then needed

Tags: c#, sql, list, algorithm

I have a list of order items and a list of inventory quantity per item

I want to get the first of each item that I will not have enough inventory

This is the list of order items

```
OrderId     Item       QtyNeeded
----------- ---------- -----------
156987      Item1025   72
156991      Item1025   55
157000      Item125    30
156986      Item1250   50
156989      Item255    20
156997      Item255    99
156992      Item3356   90
156988      Item659    60
156990      Item6598   1
156998      Item6599   105
156999      Item6600   200
156993      Item6600   105
156994      Item6602   100
156995      Item6603   30
156996      Item7809   56
```

This is the list of inventory

```
Item       QtyHave
---------- -----------
Item1025   200
Item125    20
Item1250   65
Item255    110
Item3356   100
Item659    100
Item6598   25
Item6599   100
Item6600   275
Item6602   120
Item6603   50
Item7809   75
```

I want to see a list with the first order item which I will not have enough inventory like this:

```
OrderId     Item
----------- ----------
157000      Item125
156997      Item255
156998      Item6599
156993      Item6600
```

Even better would be better to see how much is partially available

```
OrderId     Item       QtyAvailable
----------- ---------- ------------
157000      Item125    20
156997      Item255    90
156998      Item6599   100
156993      Item6600   75
```

Comment: I may not understand the question but wouldn't this just be a simple "where QtyAvailable < QtyNeeded" ?

Comment: Please also include the inventory data.

Comment: How much do you need?

Comment: Oops I forgot to add the inventory list, I updated the question

Comment: @TerryTyson For each line I could have enough but in my case I only have enough if I can fill previous lines with the same item code plus this line

Comment: Which database? Youve tagged sql which is a language. Do you mean mssql server? Also do you actually want to do this with a sql query or in C# as you tagged both!

Comment: Yes I use mssql server, I tagged both as I am open to using either of them. Tnx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return the first order item that does not meet the needed inventory:

```
select * 
from (
  select 
    *,
    case 
      when CumulativeNeededQty <= QtyHave then QtyNeeded
      when CumulativeNeededQty - QtyNeeded <= QtyHave then QtyHave - CumulativeNeededQty + QtyNeeded
      else 0
  end as PartialQty
  from (
    select 
      OrderId, 
      orders.Item, 
      orders.QtyNeeded,
      sum(QtyNeeded) over (Partition by orders.Item order by OrderID) as CumulativeNeededQty, 
      QtyHave
    from orders
    join inventory on inventory.Item = orders.Item
  ) a
) b
where PartialQty <> 0 and PartialQty <> QtyNeeded
```

And a working SQLFiddle using your example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f4973e/12

Defining "first" as the smaller OrderId means there is an error in your expected results. OrderID 156993 is before 156999, so the 4th result should actually be

```
OrderId     Item       QtyAvailable
----------- ---------- ------------
156999      Item6600   170
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite follow your expected result, if you clarify a little how you arrive by those numbers I can improve this - but hopefully this gets you started.

If you track the cumulative qty required ordered by Order id and partitioned by item, you see how many of everything you need at each step. You can then join this back to your inventory

```
with requirements as
(
  select 
    OrderId,
    Item,
    QtyNeeded,
    SUM(QtyNeeded) OVER (PARTITION BY Item ORDER BY OrderId) as CumQtyNeeded
  from orders
)
select *
from requirements r
inner join inventory i
on r.item = i.item
where r.CumQtyNeeded > i.QtyHave
```